# creating svn as a windows service is not working

Tags: windows, svn, service

i'm trying to create a windows service for svn, but it is not working. when i enter the following:

```
c:\>sc create svnserver binpath="c:\Program Files\Svn\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r c:\repo" displayname=subversion depend=Tcpip start=auto
```

it just replies with the help options for `sc`:

```
DESCRIPTION:
        Creates a service entry in the registry and Service Database.
USAGE:
        sc <server> create [service name] [binPath= ] <option1> <option2>...

OPTIONS:
NOTE: The option name includes the equal sign.
      A space is required between the equal sign and the value.
 type= <own|share|interact|kernel|filesys|rec>
       (default = own)
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled|delayed-auto>
       (default = demand)
 error= <normal|severe|critical|ignore>
       (default = normal)
 binPath= <BinaryPathName>
 group= <LoadOrderGroup>
 tag= <yes|no>
 depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
 obj= <AccountName|ObjectName>
       (default = LocalSystem)
 DisplayName= <display name>
 password= <password>
```

and the new service does not get created.

Answer (score 0):

there are a couple of errors in the original command:

- as it says in the help options - a space is required after each option's `=` sign.
- file paths which have a space in them must be double-quoted twice and the inner double quotes must be escaped (eg `"\"file path with space\""`)

so the correct command is:

```
c:\>sc create svnserver binpath= "\"c:\Program Files\Svn\bin\svnserve.exe\" --service -r c:\repo" displayname= subversion depend= Tcpip start= auto
```

and you should see a message which says

```
[SC] CreateService SUCCESS
```

to indicate that all went smoothly.